# python CLI-like variable dump

Tags: python, command-line-interface

When I use python in interactive shell I can easily dump variables by just calling their names.

```
>>> x = b'\xA5'
>>> x
'\xa5'
>>> print x
▒
```

As you can see, the behavior is different than `print`'s behavior. How do I emulate this CLI-like variable dump in normal scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=repr#repr) builtin function:

```
>>> x = '\xa5'
>>> print repr(x)
'\xa5'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = b'\xA5'
>>> print repr(x)
'\xa5'
```

Answer (score 1):

Every class can specialize their representation using the `__repr__` special method.

For example:

```
>>> class Banana:
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return "Fruit: Banana"
...
>>> Banana()
Fruit: Banana
```

It should be noted that the interactive prompt gets very grumpy (and Python in general) if you return something but a string.

It should also represent a valid Python expression if at all possible. So my example is not conforming. If a valid expression is not possible, the docs recommend `<something descriptive>`. You can see an example of this in practice if you get the representation of a class:

```
>>> Banana
<class '__main__.Banana'>
```

This special method is what `repr` and the interactive prompt use to display the object's "representation".